# Elastic Beanstalk randomly goes offline

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

My elastic beanstalk environment keeps switching the environment health from Warning to OK from OK to Warning almost every 15 minutes or so.

The Scale settings is Min: 2 max: 4 and there is 4  EC2 instances running.

Can somebody please help?
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbBQf.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell from your screenshot if new instances were created, so it can be wither the scaling trigger being met, or the load balancing one.

Your load balancer trigger is configured here:

```
Configuration => Load Balancer => EC2 Instance Health Check
```

the default value is to perform an HTTP request to the root path (/), but you can configure it as you see fit. In most cases degradation happens because your app response time isn't fast enough. You can change the parameters, or fix the app.

As for the scaling trigger, it's configured here:

```
Configuration => Scaling => Scaling Trigger
```

By default this is set to NetworkOut, which is the number of bytes sent out from the node and has nothing to do with your server being overloaded. I'm not sure why beanstalk decided to use this metric by default, but you can change it to CPU utilization or any other metric [documented here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/ec2-metricscollected.html).

Comment: The instances are being created, I'm using NetworkIn because we use the platform to upload photos.

Comment: in that case, what's the issue? you have configured it to degragate when a lot of pictures are coming in

Comment: The issue is that the instances are unstable, Getting Environment health has transitioned from Ok to Warning. 1.0 % of the requests to the ELB are failing with HTTP 5xx (3 minutes ago).

Environment health has transitioned from Ok to Warning. ELB health is failing or not available for 1 out of 4 instances. No data received from 1 out of 4 instances.

And that kind of message, But that was not happening on the same code on other region.

Comment: not sure about the region issue. you didn't mention that in your question. what value did you put in the networkin? maybe increase it if the machine works well?

Comment: Everything is default except the NetworkIn instead of NetworkOut: Trigger measurement: NetworkIn, Trigger static: Average, Unit of measurement: Bytes, Measurement period (minutes): 5, Breach duration (minutes): 5, Upper threshold: 6000000, Upper breach scale increment: 1, Lower threshold: 2000000, Lower breach scale increment: -1